# What is the equation of the following polar curve?

Tags: curves

I am trying to plot the following curve. It has 3 leaves, each leaf is identical and 120 degrees apart. It is traced as shown in the attached numbers.

[image]

My attempt is $r(\theta)=1-0.6\sin(3\theta)$ but I have no idea how to adjust it to resemble the curve above.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-3,-3)(3,3)
 \psplot[algebraic,polarplot,linecolor=red,plotpoints=100]{0}{Pi 2 mul}{1-.6*sin(3*x)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Question

What is the equation of the polar curve or parametric curve (or any kind of curve) given above?

Comment: Why do you think it is a polar curve?  That is, why do you think it has a polar equation form? It does not appear to have one, to my eye.  Would a parametric form be just as useful for you?

Comment: It looks like a [Hypotrochoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypotrochoid) to me but I can't get the parameters right to get three leaves.

Comment: A close, but not perfect, fit is (a projection of) the [trefoil knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trefoil_knot). It can be [parametrized simply](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ParametricPlot%5B%7BSin%5Bt%5D%2B1.5*Sin%5B2*t%5D,+-Cos%5Bt%5D%2B1.5*Cos%5B2*t%5D%7D,+%7Bt,+0+,+2*Pi%7D%5D).

Comment: $(\cos t+\frac34\cos(2t), \sin t-\frac34\sin(2t))$. Further reading: [Hypotrochoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypotrochoid)

Comment: @Rahul: Your answer deserves 25 points.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not what you are looking for, but, with $$f(t) = \frac{1}{3}t+\frac{3}{2}\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}t\right)-\frac{1}{5}\sin t,$$
the curve
$$
x(t)=\int_{0}^t \cos(f(u)) \, du, \,\, y(t) = \int_{0}^t \sin(f(u)) \, du
$$
looks like this:

[image: purple plane curve]

which looks like your curve if you squint.

**UPDATE:** With $$f(t) = \frac{1}{3}t+\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}t\right)-\frac{1}{5}\sin t,$$ the curve is this:
[image]

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity I improved it!

Answer (score 1):

The Adobe's logo like curve

$$(\cos t+\frac34\cos(2t), \sin t-\frac34\sin(2t))$$

mentioned in  [Rahul](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/856/rahul)'s comment is the most similar to my requirement.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\multido{\i=0+1}{51}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-2,-2)(2,2)
 \rput{36}(0,0){\psparametricplot[algebraic,polarplot,plotpoints=100,linecolor=red]
 {0}{Pi 2 mul 50 div \i\space mul}{cos(t)+3*cos(2*t)/4|sin(t)-3*sin(2*t)/4}}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]